# Ajax query returning correct value in console log, but not showing in the view

Tags: ajax, laravel, dropdown

This is my html code.

```
  <div class="form-group row add">
                        <label class="control-label col-sm-2" for="division_id">Division Name:</label>
                        <div class="col-sm-10">
                            <select name="district_id" id ="district_id" class="selectdistrict">
                                <option value="">--Select district--</option>
                               @foreach($atmdistrict as $cat)
                                <option value="{{$cat->id}}">{{$cat->name}}</option>
                                @endforeach
                            </select>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                     <div class="form-group row add">
                        <label class="control-label col-sm-2" for="thana_id">Thana Name:</label>
                        <div class="col-sm-10">
                            <select name="thana_id" class="thananame" id ="thana_id" >
                               <option value="0" disabled="true" selected="true">Thana Name</option>
                            </select>
                        </div>
                    </div>
```

This is my ajax query for dependent dropdown.

```
  $(document).ready(function(){

        $(document).on('change','.selectdistrict',function(){
         console.log("hmm its change");

            var district_id=$(this).val();
             console.log(district_id);
            var div=$(this).parent();

            var op=" ";

            $.ajax({
                type:'get',
                url:'{!!URL::to('findThanaName')!!}',
                data:{'id':district_id},
                success:function(data){
                    console.log('success');

                    console.log(data);

                    //console.log(data.length);
                    op+='<option value="0" selected disabled>chose thana</option>';
                    for(var i=0;i<data.length;i++){
                    op+='<option value="'+data[i].id+'">'+data[i].name+'</option>';
                    console.log(data[i].name);
                   }

                   div.find('.thananame').html(" ");
                 //  console.log(  div.find('.name').html(" "));
                   div.find('.select').append(op);
                   //console.log(  div.find('.select').append(op));
                },
                error:function(){
                        console.log('error');
                }
            });
        });

    });
```

The console log is showing no error, and is returning the correct data. However, the drop down menu is not showing any data. I can't figure out where I am going wrong.

[screenshot of the program running](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mI0Wj.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try to change :

```
div.find('.select').append(op);
```

by :

```
$("#thana_id").html(op);
```

Comment: I've tried. But the same result comes. It still doesn't show up in the view.

Comment: Sorry, this is the correct form : 
`$("#thana_id").html(op);`